# Is it possible to automate a data transfer from BigQuery to Google Sheets using the Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a raw data file in Google Sheets, that is populated and automatically refreshed weekly with my Big Query data. Is this possible? Is it necessary to purchase an additional service?

Comment: You should be able to use the 'Data -> Data Connectors` menu to import a table into Google Sheets (assuming you have the correct permissions). There is an option to do a 1-click refresh of the data if needed.

Comment: Are you intending to use Apps Script or Google Sheets API?